# Off meds vs Not taking your meds

Tags: word-usage

What's more likely to be used out of the two:

> How long have you been off your meds?
>
> How long haven't you been taking your meds?

Comment: They mean different things. The first means that medication is no longer necessary. The second means they are necessary, but are not being taken.

Comment: "When did you stop taking your meds" is another likely version.

Comment: @KateBunting doh! If the question went over my head, I'll add "Keep taking the meds!"

Comment: @WeatherVane the first sentence was also used to mean the what the second sentence means in a movie.......

Comment: But is it a serious question? The phrase is used, in a humorous way, to ask people who seem to have done or said something strange if they are all right.

Comment: @WeatherVane it was serious.